# Making Dapps with Flutter

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications

I have not used Plutus yet, but I’m in the pioneer program and will start soon. I am wondering if you can integrate the smart contract code with Flutter as a front end?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as long as you have a backend that runs a full node and can submit your transactions to the network. Or you could use a third party API like https://blockfrost.io to achieve the same.

Comment: Checked out blockfrost.io, I see you can send transactions and query the blockchain but I don't see anything about smart contract calls. Sorry I'm a newbie. Hope we get like an ethers.js package

Comment: Smart contracts are not supported by the blockfrost API yet since they are not available on the mainnet and testnet yet. But they should add it in the near future I think.